# Is there a relation between arithmetic and geometric series for the same a and d=q.

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Multiplication is repeated addition, so is there an explicit relation between arithmetic and geometric series if the first term is a and common difference d is equal to the common ratio q. Is it even possible to have such a case.
This is not a textbook question,just something i am curious about.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of $ (a, d) $ I use $( P,n) $ in the same sense.

The amount of money A  after n years follows Arithmetic Progression/series with rate of interest as per formula:

$ A = P( 1 + r\cdot n) $

The amount of money after n years follows Geometric Progression/series as per formula:

$ A = P( 1 + r^ n) $